# Как применить SQL скрипты с русскими символами в Win installer?

Tags: c#, .net, wix

Пишу инсталлятор (Wix installer). На этапе установки, Wix запускает SQL скрипты на создание базы данных и заполнение дефолтными значениями. Сами SQL скрипты сохранены в кодировке UTF-8 without BOM, в скриптах содержатся русские символы. Проблема заключается в том, что после выполнения установки в базе данных (MS SQL) хранятся данные с кривой нечитаемой кодировкой. Если запустить эти скрипты без инсталлятора, то данные успешно записываются в нормальной кодировке

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась - нужно сохранять все скрипты в кодировке Unicode (UTF-16).